# Cannot load default config file phantomjs

Tags: ubuntu, phantomjs, fontconfig

I installed `phantomjs` using ap-get on ubuntu, when I try to get the version of `phantomjs`

> phantomjs --version

I get this error and warning:

> Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
>
> [WARNING] phantomjs: cannot connect to X server

I tried to install `fonconfig` from the source I get the same error.

Any solution to avoid this error. Thanks

Comment: Not sure how you installed phantomjs with apt-get but [this article](http://www.pandamatak.com/people/anand/blog/2007/08/fixing_fontconfig_on_linux_wit.html) might help.

Comment: Having this issue on a vagrant vvv-apache box.